# tee with utf-8 encoding

Tags: powershell, encoding, tee, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to `tee` a server's output to both the console and a file in Powershell 4. The file is ending up with a UTF-16 encoding, which is incompatible with some other tools I'm using. According to `help tee -full`:

> Tee-Object uses Unicode enocding when it writes to files.
>   ...
>   To specify the encoding, use the Out-File cmdlet

So `tee` doesn't support changing encoding, and the help for both `tee` and `Out-File` don't show any examples of splitting a stream and encoding it with UTF-8.

Is there a simple way in Powershell 4 to `tee` (or otherwise split a stream) to a file with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: It's a shame that Microsoft chose to output in UCS2 (aka UTF-16) by default instead of UTF8...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One option is to use `Add-Content` or `Set-Content` instead of `Out-File`.

The `*-Content` cmdlets use ASCII encoding by default, and have a `-Passthru` switch so you can write to the file, and then have the input pass through to the console:

```
Get-Childitem -Name | Set-Content file.txt -Passthru
```

Comment: Can't append.. not the same.

Comment: @majkinetor The answer mentions `Add-Content`, which is for appending. Please read carefully before brushing off an answer.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, `Add-Content` is not the same as `tee`, try both commands before brushing off an answer :) `dir | Add-Content out1` vs `dir | tee out2 -Append`. Also, its not semantically correct. People use `tee` for such stuff, when you see it, you know about what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Nobody said it was the same. It can be used to the same end, though. Try `dir | Out-String | Add-Content out1 -PassThru`.

Comment: @majkinetor What exactly is "not semantically correct" about it?

Comment: this is the best solution so far, although unlike tee it locks the file

Comment: Worked for my purposes.  ty.

Answer (score 7):

You would have to use `-Variable` and then write it out to a file in a separate step.

```powershell
$data = $null
Get-Process | Tee-Object -Variable data
$data | Out-File -Path $path -Encoding Utf8
```

At first glance it seems like it's easier to avoid `tee` altogether and just capture the output in a variable, then write it to the screen and to a file.

But because of the way the pipeline works, this method allows for a long running pipeline to display data on screen as it goes along. Unfortunately the same cannot be said for the file, which won't be written until afterwards.

### Doing Both

An alternative is to roll your own `tee` so to speak:

```powershell
[String]::Empty | Out-File -Path $path  # initialize the file since we're appending later
Get-Process | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Out-File $path -Append -Encoding Utf
    $_
}
```

That will write to the file and back to the pipeline, and it will happen as it goes along. It's probably quite slow though.

Comment: The `Variable` and `Append` do not work together in tee. `Out-File` is OK sollution, but requires a function since it doesn't have `PassThru`.

Answer (score 6):

Tee-object seems to invoke out-file, so this will make tee output utf8:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{'Out-File:Encoding' = 'utf8'}
```

Comment: How can this be set as a enforced global default? so we can deploy on all windows servers.

Comment: @MortenB Try putting it in $profile.AllUsersAllHosts or $profile.AllUsersCurrentHost.

Answer (score 0):

Addressed in [the GitHub issue #11104](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11104).

**PowerShell 7.3.0 or above** supports the `-Encoding` parameter that takes one of `ASCII`, `BigEndianUnicode`, `OEM`, `Unicode`, `UTF7`, `UTF8`, `UTF8BOM`, `UTF8NoBOM` (default), and `UTF32`.

```
NAME
    Tee-Object

SYNTAX
    Tee-Object [-FilePath] <string> [-InputObject <psobject>] [-Append] [-Encoding <Encoding>] [<CommonParameters>]

    Tee-Object -LiteralPath <string> [-InputObject <psobject>] [-Encoding <Encoding>] [<CommonParameters>]

    Tee-Object -Variable <string> [-InputObject <psobject>] [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    tee


REMARKS
    Get-Help cannot find the Help files for this cmdlet on this computer. It is displaying only partial help.
        -- To download and install Help files for the module that includes this cmdlet, use Update-Help.
        -- To view the Help topic for this cmdlet online, type: "Get-Help Tee-Object -Online" or
           go to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2097034.
```

---

Even with that flag, it might still be garbled due to how PowerShell parses pipe outputs. See [#17523](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17523).

> [**@jbobrean93**](https://github.com/jborean93): PowerShell relies on [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) to parse the output from a pipe and in the absence of an explicit setting of the `Standard*Encoding` property in the start info it will rely on the global setting of `Console.OutputEncoding` to determine what encoding is used. On Windows the default console encoding is still whatever the OS is configured to, which is typically 431 on English hosts. Unfortunately your only workaround here is to set `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` and then run your command.

---

## The command to use

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
YOUR_COMMAND_HERE | Tee-Object -FilePath YOUR_OUTPUT_FILE -Encoding UTF8NoBOM
```

### Notes

You might want to update your PowerShell to use this feature. Use

```
$PSVersionTable
```

to check the version of your PowerShell.

Answer (score -1):

First create the file using appropriate flags then append to it:

```
Set-Content  out $null -Encoding Unicode
...
cmd1 | tee out -Append
...
cmdn | tee out -Append
```

Comment: this is putting null bytes between each utf8 character in the file

Comment: That is strange. I checked and it doesn't happen with `Unicode` or `UTF7` encoding.